# WebdriverIO the script that runs at the end of all test suites

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io, wdio

I have a script that needs to be run after passing all the tests, how can this be done in Wdio?

```
after: async function () {
    await deleteAllDataFromAccount()
},
```

Such code in the configuration file does not help. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand properly, but you want to run this method after a suite ends?
For this you have `afterSuite` hook.

If you want to run it after all tests from all of suites, you have `onComplete` hook. Please see the configuration file example from wdio docs (https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile).

Comment: When using the onComplete hook, an error of the type falls: it is not possible to read the undefined properties (reading 'stack')
in C:\project\e2e_tests\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\utils.js:88:53
in asyncPromise.all (index 0)
in the launcher.execute (C:\project\e2e_tests\node_modules\@wdio\cli\build\launcher .js:94:39 )